# groovy error: jars unsigned

Tags: java, security, jnlp, java-web-start, griffon

I have the following error in my app ONLY when I try to run it as a webstart or applet in griffon:

```
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. 
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:778)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:552)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:889)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Application Error: 
  Cannot grant permissions to unsigned jars. 
  Application requested security permissions, but jars are not signed.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.setSecurity(JNLPClassLoader.java:312)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init>(JNLPClassLoader.java:232)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:357)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:330)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:770)
    ... 2 more
```

what do I need to put into my code to over ride this (I am in the developing stage and not wanting to deploy just yet)?

I used the command: "griffon run-webstart -clean"

Here is my controller file:

```
package test1

import griffon.util.GriffonNameUtils as GNU
import griffon.transform.Threading

class Test1Controller {

    def model

    def clear = {
            model.griffonClass.propertyNames.each { name -> model[name] = ''
            }
    }

    @Threading(Threading.Policy.SKIP)
    def submit = {
            java.swing.JoptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            app.windowManager.windows.find{it.focused}, 
            model.griffonClass.propertyNames.collect([]) {
                     name -> "${GNU.getNaturalName(name)} = ${model[name]}"
            }.join('n')
            )
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried running `griffon clean`

Comment: tim_yates: I tried that and I still get the same error/issue

Comment: Replied to signage issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585817/griffon-programming-error-unable-to-find-class-annotation/14592555#14592555

Comment: aalmiray: I am not understanding your answer.  Can you elaborate??

Comment: @ironmantis7x: You should include the '@' before the user name when addressing people in the comments. I don't think they will get a notification if you don't.

Comment: @Steinar gave the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Steinar gave the correct answer:

> @ironmantis7x: You should include the '@' before the user name when addressing people in the comments. I don't think they will get a notification if you don't. – Steinar Mar 13 '13 at 22:51